# substituting image source on click

Tags: jquery

Firts noob here,

I have this script...

```
$.backstretch( img, options, callback );
```

I need to code this such that the image source is a variable that gets replaced when a thumbnail is clicked on, with the image link associated with that thumbnail.

Also the previous image needs to be removed because this script bunches the images together if the previous image is not removed.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Remeber noob here ... Use dummy talk please.

Comment: I just tried $.backstretch, and it returned undefined. What other scripts are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should work..

```
$('img#id').click(function () {
    this.src = "new/image.jpg"; // `this` refers to the image clicked.
});
```